# Get some pointers/suggestions on first basic java program?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

When I run the program and the user input field comes up, when I just hit enter without entering anything in the blank space another input field comes up. This happens over and over if I keep hitting enter. If there is a way to solve this please let me know. I couldn't find anything to fix it in the documentation.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class Game {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  //generate a random number
  //take user input
  //check the input act appropriately
  boolean running = true;
  boolean guessed = true;
  boolean realInt = true;


  int number = 0;
  int input = 0;

  String firstName=" ";


   System.out.print("want to play the game? Yes/No: ");
   firstName = sc.next();



  while (running) {

    if (guessed && (("yes".equals(firstName)) | ("cheater".equals(firstName)))){


        System.out.println("I have chosen a random value");
        System.out.println("Have a go at guessing it");

        Random rand = new Random();
        number = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;         

        guessed = false;


    }


     if(("yes".equals(firstName)) | ("cheater".equals(firstName)))
     {

          if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
            realInt=true;
            input = sc.nextInt();
          }
          else{
            System.out.println("That is not an integer.");
            running = false;
          }


        }

     else
      running = false;


     if((((input != number) && realInt)&&(input != -1))){
           System.out.println("Plsease try again");
         } 

    //below line sets up when to stop the program, when -1 is entered
         if (input == -1){
            running = false;
         }
         else{
           guessed = input == number;
         }

    //below lines are cheat codes   

    if (input == -5){
        System.out.println("Answer: " + number);
    }


   if ("cheater".equals(firstName) && (input != number)){
            System.out.println("Answer: " + number);

      } 


   }  


 }

}
```

Comment: I've migrated the "code review" part of your question to Code Review, but tried to keep the "it doesn't work" part of your question here (where 027's answer is great). In future, please only ask one question per question :).

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the way how `Scanner`'s `next()` method reads input.

A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

So even if you hit number of enters, there will not be any token and hence Scanner is just waiting from user to have one valid token so that in can read and continue reading the next token.

```
public String next()
```

Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

**Solution:**
Use Scanner's hasNextLine() and nextLine() methods.It will allow you to capture empty or white-space lines. Refer to the API on java site for other methods.